# Global name CustomUser is not defined

Tags: python, django

i am very new in django.i have website where i have used userena.Now for generate auto refferel code i have write some code which is copied from a forum,here is the code..

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid
import base64  
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile  
from django.db import models
from userena.utils import user_model_label 

class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,  
                        verbose_name=_('user'),related_name='my_profile')  
favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),max_length=5)
referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/profile/show/%d' % self.id

    def generate_verification_code(self):
        return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes.encode("base64").rstrip())[:25]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.referral_code = self.generate_verification_code()
        elif not self.verification_code:
            self.referral_code = self.generate_verification_code()
        return super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

now you can see at the very endline of this code i have use **super** function which have two parameter, that is CustomUser and self.Now while i am trying to run the my site ,i am facing an error which is 
**NameError: global name 'CustomUser' is not defined**,then i have change the CustomUser to **User**,then have an error 
**TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type**
now whats the actual problem,for lack of knowledge ,i can not understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `save()` method on a `MyProfile` model - it should be passed to `super()`. Also, no need for `return` here:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        self.referral_code = self.generate_verification_code()
    elif not self.verification_code:
        self.referral_code = self.generate_verification_code()
    super(MyProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks..its working and i have made a real silly mistake,infact learning process going on :)

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of *type*.

Therefore `type` must be the type that you want the proxy of, i.e. the current class.

```
return super(MyProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```